# C++ error template building

Tags: c++, templates, building

I have a problem with the build of my program. I search the error since some hour now and i don't understand what is the problem.

Here is my code :
ListeBase.h

```
    #ifndef LISTEBASE_H
    #define LISTEBASE_H
    #include "Timing.h"
    #include "Professeur.h"
    #include "Cours.h"
    #include "Local.h"
    #include "Groupe.h"
template<class T> struct Cellule
{
    T Valeur ;
    Cellule<T> *psuivant ;
};

template <class T> class ListeBase
{
    protected:
        Cellule<T> *Ptete;
    public:
        ListeBase();
        ListeBase(ListeBase<T>& LB);
        virtual ~ListeBase();
        Cellule<T> * getTete(void)const;
        void setTete(Cellule<T> *Te);
        int estVide(void)const;
        int getNombreElements(void)const;
        void Affiche(void);
        virtual T* insere(const T& val)=0;
};

#endif
```

ListeBase.cpp

```
#include "../Header/ListeBase.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T> ListeBase<T>::ListeBase()
{
    cout << "Methode Constructeur ListeBase" << endl;
    Ptete=0;
}
template <class T> ListeBase<T>::ListeBase(ListeBase<T>& LB)
{
    setTete(LB.getTete());
}
template <class T> ListeBase<T>::~ListeBase()
{
    Cellule<T> *Temp,*Test;

    cout << "Methode destructeur ListeBase" << endl;    
    do
    {
        Temp=Ptete->psuivant;
        delete Ptete; // IL FALLAIT UN OPERATOR= DE TIMING SINON IL Y AVAIT DEUX ELEMENT A LA MEME ADRESSE
        Ptete=Temp;
    }while(Ptete!=0);
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
 template <class T> Cellule<T>* ListeBase<T>::getTete(void)const
{
    cout << "Methode getTete" << endl;
    return Ptete;
}
template <class T> void ListeBase<T>::setTete(Cellule<T> *Te)
{
    cout << "Methode SetTete" << endl;
    if(Te!=0)
        this->Ptete=Te;
}
template <class T> int ListeBase<T>::estVide(void)const
{
    if(getTete()==0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
template <class T> int ListeBase<T>::getNombreElements(void)const
{
    Cellule<T> *Temp;
    int i=0;

    Temp=getTete();

    while((*Temp).psuivant!=0)
    {
        i++;
        Temp=(*Temp).psuivant;
    }

    return i;
}
template <class T> void ListeBase<T>::Affiche(void)
{
    Cellule<T> *Temp;
    int i=0;

    cout << "Methode affiche" << endl;
    Temp=getTete();
    while(Temp!=0)
    {
        cout << Temp->Valeur << endl;
        Temp=Temp->psuivant;
    }
    cout << "FIN AFFICHE" << endl;
}
template class ListeBase<int>;
template class ListeBase<Timing>;
template class ListeBase<Professeur>;
template class ListeBase<Groupe>;
template class ListeBase<Local>;
template class ListeBase<Cours>;
```

Liste.cpp

```
  #include "../Header/Liste.h"

    template <class T> Liste<T>::Liste():ListeBase<T>()
    {
        cout << "Methode COnstructeur Liste" << endl;
    }
    template <class T> Liste<T>::Liste(const Liste<T>& L)
    {
        cout << "Methode COnstructeur Liste COPIE" << endl;
        this->setTete(L.getTete());
    }
    template <class T> Liste<T>::~Liste()
    {
        cout << "Methode Destructeur Liste" << endl;
    }
    template <class T> T* Liste<T>::insere(const T& Val)
    {
        Cellule<T>* Temp;
        Temp=new Cellule<T>;
        cout << "Methode insere Liste" << endl;
        Temp->psuivant=this->getTete();
        Temp->Valeur=Val;
        this->setTete(Temp);

        return &this->getTete()->Valeur;    
    }

    template class Liste<int>;
    template class Liste<Timing>;
    template class Liste<Professeur>;
    template class Liste<Groupe>;
    template class Liste<Local>;
    template class Liste<Cours>;
```

Liste.h

```
    #ifndef LISTE_H
    #define LISTE_H

    #include "ListeBase.h"
    #include "Groupe.h"
    #include "Professeur.h"
    #include "Local.h"
    #include "Cours.h"

    template <class T> 
    class Liste : public ListeBase<T>
    {
        public:
            Liste();
            Liste(const Liste<T>& L);
            ~Liste();
            T* insere(const T& Val);
    };

    #endif
```

Cours.h

```
#ifndef COURS_H
#define COURS_H

#include "Liste.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "Professeur.h"

class Cours:public Event
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& s,const Cours& C);

    private:
        char* Prof;
        Liste<int> Groupes;
    public:
        Cours();
        Cours(const int Code,const char* Intitule,const char* Lieu,const Timing& timing, Professeur& P);
        Cours(const int Code,const char* Intitule,const char* Lieu,const Timing& timing, Professeur& P,Liste<int>&G);
        Cours(const Cours& C);

        Cours& operator=(const Cours& C);

        int operator>(const Cours& C)const;//
        int operator<(const Cours& C)const;// DEMANDE DEXPLICATION SUR LA VALEUR DU RETURN
        int operator==(const Cours& C)const;//
        int compH(const Cours& C)const; 

        Liste<int> getGroupes(void)const;
        void setGroupes(const Liste<int> G);
        char* getProf(void)const;
        void setProf(const char* P);

};


#endif
```

This is the error message:

```
In file included from Cpp/../Header/Cours.h:4:0,
                 from Cpp/../Header/ListeBase.h:6,
                 from Cpp/ListeBase.cpp:1:

Cpp/../Header/Liste.h:11:31: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
 class Liste : public ListeBase<T>
                               ^
Cpp/../Header/Liste.h:11:31: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token

Cpp/../Header/Liste.h:11:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token

In file included from Cpp/../Header/ListeBase.h:6:0,
                 from Cpp/ListeBase.cpp:1:

Cpp/../Header/Cours.h:15:14: error: field ‘Groupes’ has incomplete type
   Liste<int> Groupes;
```

Thanks a lot for you Help :/

Comment: Implementation of template should be accessible during compilation time => so implementation of template should be in header

Comment: Also, can we have ListeBase.h please ?

Comment: Sure, i have update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular include :

ListeBase.cpp -> ListeBase.h -> Cours.h -> Liste.h -> ListeBase.h

When including Liste.h at this moment, class ListeBase is unknown. Cirular include is stopped with #ifndef LISTEBASE_H

Change your design (I'm not sure a base template has to include some applicative header)

Also, as mention before, template implementation has to be known during compilation time, so implementation should be in header, not in a source file

---

**EDIT**

The common way of using template:

ListeBase.h which defines and implements ListeBase ONLY

Liste.h which defines and implements Liste, which inherint from BaseListe

Every header or source which needs using template have to include Liste.h and use it directly, without declarating anything in an cpp before

With our design, it seems to me difficult to use a CPP to define template. according circular include

I recommend you to use this way. It's the right way.

Note : you can see "extern" keyword for template (only C++11)

---

**EDIT2**

In every situation, It's important to minimize dependencies, so, At any time, when including a header, think about that : "Is my implementation/header really needs to know this ?" and "Which file use which ?"

For the last question, if the response involves a ciruclar dependency, there is a design mistake

Comment: I don't understand. If i want to use a variable of Liste in my class Cours. I must to include List.h in my header. And if i want to use a template of cours,Local, Groupe, Professeur. I must declare the prototype for the compiler bellow the cpp of Liste and ListeBase and if i put the prototype with the type i must include the header in the header of my class template no ? ( sorry for my english :p )

Comment: I have already make another program with this method, the implementation in a source file and there was no problem, that's why i don't understand what it happen here

Comment: I understand what you do, it's not the common way (see my edit), and your design involves circular inclusion and so compilation problem

Comment: If i understand, all my method in my ListeBase.cpp i put directly in my .h. And the same for my Liste.h ?

Comment: Yes it's that, and you have to remove `template class Liste<int>;
    template class Liste<Timing>;
    template class Liste<Professeur>;
    template class Liste<Groupe>;
    template class Liste<Local>;
    template class Liste<Cours>;` from Liste.cpp before (same for ListeBase.cpp). With this method, you don't have to declare use of template in template implementation and remove circular dependency

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)